# Replacing multiple classes in multiple HTML DOM elements with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a few elements:
HTML:

```html
<button class="btn-post">Post</button>
<button class="btn-post">Post</button>
<button class="btn-post">Post</button>
<button class="btn-post">Post</button>
```

As you can see, these buttons have the class `btn-post` and when someone clicks a button and activates an event.

I want to replace all the `btn-post` classes with `btn btn-success` (`btn` and `btn-success`)
Any helpful advice?

Comment: Loop through elements selected with `querySelectorAll`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn-post")

btns.forEach(btn => {
  btn.onclick = () => btns.forEach(_btn => _btn.className = "btn btn-success")
})
```

```css
.btn-post {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.btn-success {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-post">Post</button>
<button class="btn-post">Post</button>
<button class="btn-post">Post</button>
<button class="btn-post">Post</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to do so.

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-post");

for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].className = "btn btn-success";
}
```

Comment: This won't work. See [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the elements with class `bln-post`, and create an array from it. You can then edit the class names using `classList` API.

```js
const elems = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-post')

Array.from(elems).forEach(el => {
  el.classList.remove('btn-post');
  el.classList.add('btn');
  el.classList.add('btn-success');
})
```

```css
.btn-success {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-post">Post</button>
<button class="btn-post">Post</button>
<button class="btn-post">Post</button>
<button class="btn-post">Post</button>
```